# How can we interpret the Cosmographic parameters?

Tags: cosmology

I read that one way to find the Hubble parameter and the deceleration parameter is doing a Taylor series expansion of the scale factor with respect to the cosmic time and we find that

H(t)$\equiv\frac{1}{a}\frac{da}{dt}$

q(t)$\equiv-\frac{1}{a}\frac{d^2a}{dt^2}\frac{1}{H^2}$

But there are other ones that they called the jerk, snap and lerk parameters

j(t)$\equiv\frac{1}{a}\frac{d^3a}{dt^3}\frac{1}{H^3}$,
s(t)$\equiv\frac{1}{a}\frac{d^4a}{dt^4}\frac{1}{H^4}$,

l(t)$\equiv\frac{1}{a}\frac{d^5a}{dt^5}\frac{1}{H^5}$.

My question is if these parameters give us some information like the Hubble parameter which tell us the expansion rate or the deceleration parameter with the acceleration rate.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 1):

In principle, yes, all of those derivatives of $a(t)$ are interesting. However, in modern cosmology we actually have vastly more information than are contained in a finite number of derivatives of $a$, since we have a standard model that produces $H(z)$ -- the expansion rate of the Universe as a function of redshift (effectively, time) -- and which has been observationally probed throughout several different epochs of the Universe's history. There is some debate about whether the [tension in the value of the expansion rate today](https://arxiv.org/abs/2103.01183) implies that the standard model for $H(z)$ is incorrect at early redshifts, but no conclusive evidence of this and so far the standard cosmological model remains the best, simplest model that explains the totality of observational evidence.

The deceleration parameter is mostly of historical interest. In the mid-to-late 90s, it was widely believed that the cosmological constant was zero. A measurement of the deceleration parameter could be done with Type 1a supernovae and would allow cosmologists to distinguish the case of a matter dominated Universe with no spatial curvature, and a universe with matter and (negative) spatial curvature. Since the presence of negative spatial curvature would ultimately lead to a collapsing Universe, while zero curvature would lead to a Universe that expanded forever, the question of which model better fit observations was sometimes referred to as "density is destiny." As it turned out, neither model was correct, and there is now strong evidence that the Universe is *accelerating* due to a cosmological constant (or, some form of dark energy that acts exactly like a cosmological constant as far as we can tell).

However, as I said before, today the state of the art has advanced far beyond measuring time derivatives of $a(t)$ at the Universe today, and we probe the expansion history through many different epochs of the Universe's history.